# How to avoid repeating the exported functions in the manifest(*.psd1) and the module file(*.psm1)?

Tags: powershell

I'm building a PowerShell module. It contains several public functions as well as a number of private utility functions. I want for the users of the module to know only about the public functions.

I've created `Project.psm1`.

```
. "${PSScriptRoot}\public\Foo.ps1"

Export-ModuleMember -Function Foo
```

Because I intend to publish the module to the PowerShell Gallery, I also need to have a manifest file. I've created a script that will generate a manifest for the project.

```
New-ModuleManifest `
    -Guid 'd1f545c4-49db-4fd8-bc14-53df36387757' `
    -Path path\to\project `
    -RootModule "Project.psm1" `
    -FunctionsToExport 'Foo'
```

I don't like that I have to specify `Foo` in 2 places. If I rename or delete `Foo`, or add a new function to export, I will have to change two files and eventually, I will forget about one of them.

Is there a way to have all the functions to export specified in a single place?

Comment: But you dont need to (?) the functions to export in your manifest should suffice

Comment: What makes you think you need to use `Export-ModuleMember -Function Foo` in your `.psm1` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The tutorial I was following was using it.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: The MS documentation [How to Write a PowerShell Script Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7.2#create-a-basic-powershell-module) states: "*To control user access to certain functions or variables, call Export-ModuleMember at the end of your script....it's recommended you explicitly call out which functions you wish to expose...*" and while it goes on to menton module manifests, it doesn't explicity say `Export-ModuleMember` is unnecessary when a manifest is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The exports explicitly specified in a [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) (`.psd1` file) *additionally constrain* the *implicit or explicit* exports of a script module (`.psm1` file).
- *Implicitly* - in the *absence* of an `Export-ModuleMember` call - a script module exports *all* its (a) functions and (b) aliases, but *not* its variables.

Given that exporting *variables* from modules is best avoided,<sup>[1]</sup> there is usually *no* reason to use [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) in a script module file.

Thus, controlling what functions (and aliases) your module exports need only be maintained in the `FunctionsToExport` (`AliasesToExport`) entry of the module manifest.

---

<sup>[1] Not only would exporting variables increase the risk of name collisions, it also presents a *discoverability* problem; generally, users expect modules only to export *commands*, which can be discovered with `Get-Command` and help for which can be requested with `Get-Help` / `-?`.</sup>